# Present the current View Controller with different data

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller, and when a certain button is selected, the current view controller should present another version of itself so I can go back. Here is what I have:

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton){
    let controller = MyVC()
    controller.txt =  txts[sender.tag]
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. When I run this code I get a "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error message coming from my storyboard items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you not need to present controller again. just change data. if there are any changes in UI then you can hide and show it or can add or remove from super view. and if you require to presentviewcontroller compulsory then use new viewcontroller to present. you can't present already presenting controller.

hope this will help :)

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. But I am using a navigation controller and would like the back button to work.

Comment: then present or push new view controller.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure out how to push it!